# Is the magnitude of the gradient of the tensor ellipsoid constant over the surface?

Tags: tensor-calculus, moment-of-inertia, textbook-erratum

The following is from Lagrangian Dynamics by D.A. Wells:

> It can be shown that the direction cosines $l,m,n$ of a line drawn normal to the surface $\phi\left[x,y,z\right]=C$ are proportional to $\partial\phi/\partial x,\partial\phi/\partial y,\partial\phi/\partial z$ respectively, that is,
>
> $$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}=kl,\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}=km,\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}=kn$$
>
> where $k$ is a *constant*. Applying these relations to the ellipsoidal surface
>
> $$I_{x}x^{2}+I_{y}y^{2}+I_{z}z^{2}-2I_{xy}xy-2I_{yz}yz-2I_{zx}zx=1,$$
>
> we have
>
> $$I_{x}x-I_{xy}y-I_{zx}z=kl$$
>
> $$I_{y}y-I_{xy}x-I_{yz}z=km$$
>
> $$I_{z}z-I_{xz}x-I_{yz}y=kn.$$

Am I correct in understanding that, in general, the "constant" $k$ varies from place to place on the surface of constant $\phi?$ If I am, in fact correct, one might argue that the statement in the book is not an error, per se. But it sure seems misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, $k$ is not a constant over the whole surface. The gradient vector $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi=\big(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x},\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y},\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}\big)$ consists of a magnitude and a direction. The (normalized) direction cosines $(l,m,n)$ give us the direction; $k$ gives us the magnitude $|\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi|$. In general $|\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi|$ is not constant for a given $\phi$ on a surface $\phi(x,y,z)=C$, and in particular it is not constant for a nonspherical ellipsoid. (Obviously in the special case of a spherical inertia tensor, which is diagonal and has $I_x=I_y=I_z$,
$|\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi|$ would be constant over the whole spherical surface).

The book is using the word "constant" in the context of that handful of equations, to mean "constant of proportionality".